# Erro ao Inserir o resultado de um SELECT em tabelas de bancos diferentes MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou recebendo um erro ao gerar um select e em seguida dar um insert, tenhos 2 bancos diferentes mas no mesmo servidor e estou dando um select no banco registro_duplicado(banco de origem) cujo a tabela é registro e dando um insert para o banco de destino que é o migracao_teste cuja tabela é sites as duas tabelas tem as mesmas colunas e tipos, minha conexao.php.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$bdOrigem   = 'registro_duplicado';
$bdDestino  = 'migracao_teste';
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Falha na 
conexão com o BD " . $conn->connect_error);
mysql_select_db($bdOrigem , $conn) or die('Não foi possível selecionar o BD 
'. $bdOrigem );
```

Um arquivo chamado funcao.php.

```
function consulta($sql){
//gera o SQL
$result = mysql_query($sql);
//se o SQL est´acorreto
if (!$result) {die('SQL Invalido: ' . mysql_error());}
//se tem resultados
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //retorna os dados
    return $result;
}else{
    return false;
}   
}
```

E o sites.php onde gero o select e o insert.

```
 require('conexao.php');
 require('funcoes.php');
 $sql = 'SELECT registros.id AS id, registros.descricao AS descricao, 
 registros.observacao as observacao
 FROM registro_duplicado.registro AS registros
 ORDER BY registros.id';
 $registros = consulta($sql);
 $insert = null;
 if($registros){ 
   while ($registro = mysql_fetch_array($registros)) {
     $id = $registro['id'];
     $descricao = ((!empty($registro['descricao'])) ? 
     utf8_encode($registro['descricao']) : '');
     $observacao = ((!empty($registro['observacao'])) ? $registro['observacao'] 
     . '.site.localhost' : '');
     $insert .= "INSERT INTO sites (descricao, observacao) VALUES 
     ('{$descricao}', '{$observacao}');";
   } 
 } else {
    echo 'Nenhum resultado encontrado';
 }
 if (!empty($insert)) {
    print "<pre>";
    print($insert);
    print "</pre>";
    mysql_select_db($bdDestino , $conn) or die('Não foi possível selecionar o BD 
    '.$bdDestino );
    $result = mysql_query($insert);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
 }
 mysql_close($conn);
 header('Content-Type: text/plain;');
 print($insert);
```

Quando dou o F5 no navegador eu tenho o erro abaixo:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'INSERT INTO sites (descricao, observacao) VALUES ('REGISTRO 2', 'teste.site.loca'` at line 1

E o erro acontece no momento que ele vai dar um insert no segundo registro, se colocar um LIMIT de 1 ele gera a consulta e grava o insert no banco

Comment: @DavidSam retirei o penúltimo ";" desta linha e o erro permaneceu e se tirar o último da erro no fechamento da chave

Comment: está certo. Meu comentário estava errado mesmo, até apaguei. O que me parece é que está vindo do primeiro banco algum caractere que está quebrando a query do MySQL, como a aspas simples ou aspas dupla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia Henrique. Estive observando o código e percebi que seu objectivo é inserir o resultado do select em outra tabela de outro banco no mesmo servidor. Se não houver nenhuma necessidade em trabalhar com o retorno do select você pode utilizar a seguinte query:

```
INSERT INTO migracao_teste.sites (descricao, observacao)
SELECT
    registros.descricao AS descricao, 
    registros.observacao as observacao
FROM registro_duplicado.registro AS registros
ORDER BY registros.id'
```

Comment: Bom dia Bilico, o retorno não é tão importante, o problema é que preciso concatenar a coluna observação, exemplo, nela eu tenho as informações de domínio que hoje estão como curitiba e preciso adicionar um subdomínio, ou seja preciso que fique por exemplo curitiba.teste.localhost, da forma que mencionou funciona se eu for passar direto as informações sem concatenar nada, e tenho muitos registros pra fazer um a um, acredito que pra fazer isso direto pelo sql não tenha como, ou tem alguma forma?

Comment: pode trabalhar com IF ELSE no select, exemplo:
**if(registros.descricao != '' or registros.descricao is not null, concat(registro.descricao, '.site.localhost'), '') as descricao**
e depois usar o mesmo para observacao

Comment: Fecho o balão, isso aí mata meu problema, obrigado pela ajuda